# How do I set initial state in an Angular Universal application?

Tags: angular, window, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am in the process of upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 4 + Universal. In previous versions, I was using a store state in a reducer to set the initial state. The `getInitialState` function would set the state, then check the cache for any previous values and update the state. The state is then returned in the exported default function `user`.

```
function getInitialState() {
let initialState;
const emptyState = {
    categories: null,
    seeAllUsers: null,
    groups: userGroupExists(),
    formData: null,
    bonusSeeAllUsers: null,
    fetching: false,
    searchResults: null
};
if (isBrowser) { // here is my problem
    if (window['UNIVERSAL_CACHE'] !== undefined) {
        const cache = JSON.parse(window['UNIVERSAL_CACHE'].CacheService);
        if (cache) {
            initialState = {
                groups: cache.groups ? updateGroups(cache.groups) : null,
                seeAllUsers: cache.seeAllUsers ? updateSeeAllUsers(cache.seeAllUsers) : null,
                groups: userGroupExists(),
                formData: null,
                bonusSeeAllUsers: null,
                fetching: false,
                searchResults: null
            };
        } else {
          initialState = emptyState;
        }
    } else {
        initialState = emptyState;
    }
} else {
    initialState = emptyState;
}
return initialState;
}

export default function user(state: any = initialState, action: Action{
      switch (action.type) {
        case TYPES.RECEIVE_USERS_SEE_ALL_BEGIN:
          let nextSeeAllBeginState;
          if (action.payload.data === 0) {
            return assign({}, state, {
            seeAllUsers: {},
            bonusSeeAllUsers: {},
            fetching: true
           });
          }
        }    
    }
```

Since the recent updates to Angular Universal, its required to inject the `PLATFORM_ID` into the constructor to check if the code is running on the browser or server like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID)platformId: string){
    isPlatformBrowser(platformId){
        // access window
    };
}
```

Since reducers cannot use any Angular decorators, how can utilize the values in the cache to update my state?